# Unix C files , scanf is ignoring whitespace

Tags: c, file, unix, terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main (int argc, char* arcv[]) {
    int fd, quest_num, i, j; 
    char* str; 
    char temp[2], buffer[20];

    fd = open(arcv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0664);

    printf("Insert number of questions\n");
    scanf("%s", str);

    write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
    write(fd, "\n", 1);
    quest_num = atoi(str);

    for (i = 1; i <= quest_num; i++) {
        printf("Insert question %d\n", i);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", buffer);
        printf("\n %s \n", buffer);
        write(fd, "Question ", );
        sprintf(temp, "%d", i);
        write(fd, temp, sizeof(temp));
        write(fd, "\n", 1);
        write(fd, str, sizeof(temp));
        write(fd, "\n", 1);
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

I want to make inputs like this:

```
Insert Number of Question:
 
2
 
Insert Question 1:

X+1=0 x=?

Insert Question 2:
 
X+y=0
```

and inside the file content i want it to look like this:

```
Question 1: X+1=0 x=?
1. 5
2. 2
3. 0
4. 1 Question 2: X+y=0
1. X=y
2. X= y
3. X=1
4. Y=1
```

but I get this in the terminal:

```
Insert number of questions

2
 
Insert question 1

x+y x=?

Insert question 2 (input is ignored here)
```

and inside the file:

```
2
 
Question 1

x+

Question 2

x=
 
Question 3

2
```

So in summary, `scanf` is ignoring the spaces input and there's an extra loop in the file content.

Comment: Why do you have `s` after `%[^\n]`? That will never match anything.

Comment: @Barmar I tried %[^\n]s, %[^\n] and %s. None of them works

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `str`, so you're causing undefined behavior with `scanf("%s", str);`.

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of characters that were entered. Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string.

Comment: After you use `scanf("%s")`, the input buffer is left at the newline. The next `scanf("%[^\n]s", buffer);` will stop immediately because there's no non-newline characters.

Comment: Why don't you use `scanf("%d")` to read a number, instead of reading a string and then using `atoi()`?

Comment: If you want to read lines, the best way is with `fgets()`.

Comment: Never use `atoi()`.  It has no way to indicate any error on bad input.  Use `strtol()` or `strtoll()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that when you scanf something that doesn't match a newline (either `%s` or `%[^\n]`) it won't read the newline at the end of the line and will leave it for the next stdio input rountine to read.  You need to actually read and discard those newlines somehow.

The easiest way to do this is to use `fgets` to read input lines instead of `scanf`.

```
    printf("Insert number of questions\n");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    quest_num = atoi(buffer);

    for (i = 1; i <= quest_num; i++) {
        printf("Insert question %d\n", i);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

Note that `fgets` will read the line *including* the newline, and the newline will be in the buffer, so if you don't want it, you'll need to strip it out explicitly.

If you really must use scanf, you can use a space in the format to explicitly skip over leading whitespace (including any lingering newline(s)), which might actually be desirable.

```
    printf("Insert number of questions\n");
    scanf("%19s", buffer);

    write(fd, str, strlen(buffer));
    write(fd, "\n", 1);
    quest_num = atoi(buffer);

    for (i = 1; i <= quest_num; i++) {
        printf("Insert question %d\n", i);
        scanf("% 19[^\n]", buffer);
        printf("\n %s \n", buffer);
```

Note that when using scanf with `%s` or `%[` and a fixed-size buffer, you should use an explicit size in the format to avoid buffer overruns